# Distancia no maps maior que 50 Km e pins sendo marcados ao limite de 20 no mapa

Tags: android, google-maps

Boa noite.

O maps mostra no máximo 20 pins marcados ao redor de onde estou.

Estou fazendo chamadas no Retrofit para pegar a localização desses pins, pois estou trazendo por tipo de categoria de estabelecimento.

Tem algum modo de colocar distancia no Maps a partir de 50 km do local que estou e marcar com mais de 20 pins ao mesmo tempo?

Descobri agora a pouco que existe paginação por token quando faço essas chamadas no serviço, mas ainda não resolvi o problema.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Como assim distância maior quem 50km? Tem como exemplificar melhor. Não está muito claro.

Comment: Por exemplo, quero trazer pins há uma distancia maior que 50 km.
Percebi que o mapa marca só 20 pins e fui pesquisar a fundo pois estou usando maps com retrofit.
Descobri nesse exato momento que existe um método que faz a paginação do serviço para trazer mais pins em uma grande distancia, entendeu?